# How to draw the area that cover given points on listplot in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, envelope

I have a lot of points' coordinates. I drew them on a 2d plot with ListPlot, and the points cover an area. Then I need to get the region that cover these points. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73913/how-to-draw-the-area-that-cover-given-points-on-listplot